# vuejs model for checkbox group

Tags: arrays, vue.js, checkboxlist

I have 2 arrays one for possible checkbox variants and one for already saved-checked boxes.VUEJS template for example

```
<ul>
                <li v-for="cit in possable">
                    <label>
                    <input  
                        type="checkbox"
                        :checked="savedcbx.indexOf(+cit.id)>-1"
                        :value="cit.id"/>
                    {{cit.rname}}
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

And my question about how add new checkedbox to saved array or delete from saved array uncheckedbox&

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just put savedcbx to model and it works like in answer above.
Vue great thing.

```
             <ul>
            <li v-for="cit in possable">
                <label>
                <input  
                    type="checkbox"
                    v-model="savedcbx"

                    //with model this not need too 
                    :checked="savedcbx.indexOf(+cit.id)>-1"
                    :value="cit.id"/>
                {{cit.rname}}
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: This means your question was unclear. You asked how to add/remove elements to the `savedcbx`, by using v-model whenever a checkbox is checked/unchecked the `savedcbx` will be changed. Anyway, yes, if you want to have a list of currently checked checkboxes just use `v-model`.

Answer (score 14):

You only need one array to achieve toggling. From the [Arrays section of Vue.js docs:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox)

HTML:

```
<div id='example-3'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="jack">Jack</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="john">John</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="mike">Mike</label>
  <br>
  <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
</div>
```

Vue app:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#example-3',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

So, assuming you have this data:

```
data() {
  return {
    possable: [1,2,3,4,5],
    savedcbx: [3,4]
   }
}
```

If you want to add a new item into `savedcbx` you just have to push it into the array (make sure it doesn't exist already)

```
addSavedId (id) {
  // Don't add it if it already exists
  if(this.savedcbx.indexOf(id) !== -1) return;

  this.savedcbx.push(id);
}
```

To remove an item:

```
removeSavedId (id) {
  let index = this.savedcbx.indexOf(id);

  // Nothing to remove if item is not in array
  if(index === -1) return;

  // Remove `index`
  this.savedcbx.splice(index, 1);
}
```

And now it's up to you when you call the `addSavedId(id)` and `removeSavedId(id)` functions and what is the parameter `id`.

Comment: @lauri108 That doesn't explain how to link the checked checkboxes to his `savedcbx` array. It only works if by "saved" checkboxes he meant "checked" checkboxes.